# Posso incluir vários certificados em um arquivo .jks para configurar em um só Client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, certificado-digital, keystore

Eu tenho um micro serviço que é utilizado por três empresas, nesse micro serviço eu faço a busca de um token em outra empresa externa, para cada empresa chamadora preciso usar um certificado diferente.
Eu posso incluir todos os certificados em um .jks para que independente da empresa que chamar, a configuração de certificação no Client já está de acordo ?

```
public class FeignClientConsultaSngConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JksProperties jksProperties;

    @Bean
    public Client feignClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContextBuilder contextBuilder = createSSLContextBuilder();
        return new Client.Default(contextBuilder.build().getSocketFactory(), HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder createSSLContextBuilder() {
        if (jksProperties != null && jksProperties.getValues() != null) {
            return createContextWithKeyStores(jksProperties);
        }
        return SSLContextBuilder.create();
    }

    public SSLContextBuilder createContextWithKeyStores(JksProperties jksProperties) {
        SSLContextBuilder contextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create();
        contextBuilder.setProtocol("TLS");
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, JksProperties.Credential> entry : jksProperties.getValues().entrySet()) {

                String stringPath = entry.getValue().getPath();
                String stringPass = entry.getValue().getPass();
                char[] charArrayPass = getKeyPassword(stringPass);
                KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore(charArrayPass, stringPath);
                contextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, charArrayPass);
                contextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException | CertificateException |
                 IOException e) {
        }
        return contextBuilder;
    }

    char[] getKeyPassword(String keyPass) {
        byte[] decodedPassword = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyPass);
        char[] keyPassword = new char[decodedPassword.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < decodedPassword.length; i++) {
            keyPassword[i] = (char) decodedPassword[i];
        }
        return keyPassword;
    }

    private KeyStore getKeyStore(char[] keyPassword, String keyPath)
            throws IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(keyPath)), keyPassword);
        return keyStore;
    }



}
´´´´
```

Answer (score -5):

Sim, você pode incluir todos os certificados em um arquivo JKS (Java KeyStore) para que o seu microserviço seja capaz de lidar com diferentes certificados dependendo da empresa chamadora. A implementação que você compartilhou parece estar indo na direção certa.

Aqui estão algumas considerações e sugestões:

Verificação de Certificado por Nome de Domínio (Hostname Verification):
Certifique-se de que você está considerando a verificação do nome de domínio (hostname verification) ao criar o SSLContextBuilder. Você já incluiu o HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier(), o que é bom para verificação padrão.

Tratamento de Exceções:
No bloco catch, seria útil registrar ou tratar as exceções adequadamente, para que você possa diagnosticar problemas de carregamento do keystore ou problemas de comunicação SSL.

Senhas e Segurança:
Certifique-se de tratar as senhas de forma segura. Atualmente, você está convertendo uma senha de base64 para um array de caracteres. Certifique-se de que essa abordagem é adequada para suas necessidades de segurança.

Encerramento de Recursos:
Ao trabalhar com Files.newInputStream, certifique-se de fechar o InputStream após o uso para evitar vazamentos de recursos. Uma abordagem comum é usar um bloco try-with-resources.

Aqui está uma pequena modificação sugerida para incluir o tratamento de exceções e o encerramento de recursos:

```
public SSLContextBuilder createContextWithKeyStores(JksProperties jksProperties) throws KeyStoreException {
    SSLContextBuilder contextBuilder = SSLContextBuilder.create();
    contextBuilder.setProtocol("TLS");
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

    try {
        for (Map.Entry<String, JksProperties.Credential> entry : jksProperties.getValues().entrySet()) {
            String stringPath = entry.getValue().getPath();
            String stringPass = entry.getValue().getPass();
            char[] charArrayPass = getKeyPassword(stringPass);
            KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore(charArrayPass, stringPath);
            contextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, charArrayPass);
            contextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Trate as exceções de carregamento de keystore, SSL, etc.
        e.printStackTrace(); // Ajuste conforme necessário
        throw new KeyStoreException("Erro ao criar o SSLContextBuilder", e);
    }

    return contextBuilder;
}

private KeyStore getKeyStore(char[] keyPassword, String keyPath) throws KeyStoreException {
    try (InputStream keyStoreStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(keyPath))) {
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, keyPassword);
        return keyStore;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Trate as exceções de carregamento de keystore, SSL, etc.
        e.printStackTrace(); // Ajuste conforme necessário
        throw new KeyStoreException("Erro ao carregar o keystore", e);
    }
}
```

Essas são apenas sugestões e ajustes. Adapte conforme necessário para as suas necessidades específicas. Certifique-se de testar adequadamente em um ambiente controlado para garantir que a configuração de SSL funcione conforme o esperado.